# Java daemon under Linux: Choices?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, daemon

I have a console application (written in Java), which should run on a Linux machine until it is stopped.

Logging is done by the application itself.

The application needs to be stopped whenever a new version is available (i. e. I login, stop the application, copy the new JAR file, and then launch it again).

What are the options for implementing this, apart from those specified below?

Known ways to do it:

1) Tanuki service wrapper

2) nohup java -jar myapp-1.32.jar &

Comment: Even though it doesn't fit your needs completely, you can have a look at capistrano.

Comment: Take care to find a service that makes it possible to listen to shutdown signals to shutdown your service gracefully.

Comment: Will your console application be able to detect that it needs to shut down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some modern Linux distributions have switched to [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/). That's a daeomon starting and stopping all the other services. I'd definitely look into that. Since it solves some tricky problems with production ready start scripts. The downside is that it has no java specific functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The link you posted refers to a Wikipedia article about external sort. I don't understand what it has to do with upstart.

Answer (score 6):

I use [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/), but you already mentioned it. I think it should suit your needs.

Apache Commons Daemon is also popular: http://commons.apache.org/daemon/, but I never used it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this startup script: http://shrubbery.homeip.net/c/display/W/Java+Daemon+Startup+Script

[Changed domain name - by wiki owner]

Comment: The link should be  http://shrubbery.homeip.net/c/display/W/Java+Daemon+Startup+Script

Answer (score 0):

There also the apache commons deamons http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html

> Jsvc is a set of libraries and applications for making Java applications run on UNIX more easily.
>
> Jsvc allows the application (e.g. Tomcat) to perform some privileged operations as root (e.g. bind to a port < 1024), and then switch identity to a non-privileged user.